# Extra heat gets added out of nowhere when using Thermo Aquatuner

Tags: oxygen-not-included

### Problem Statement

I decided to test my understanding of heat exchange and temperature handling in Oxygen Not Included. So I used Sandbox and Dev Mode to set up a simple heating loop and then tried to calculate the resulting temperature of the liquid I was heating.

Alas, the lab test results diverged from my calculations by a lot. I would appreciate any help finding flaws in my reasoning.

### Lab Setup

#### Design

[image: Design]

#### Pipes

[image: Pipes]

#### Wiring

[image: Wires]

### Heating

All the materials inside the box started at **10.0 ℃**.

[image: Initial State]

Then I fed **4 kg** worth of *Super Coolant* at **-35.1 ℃** to the *Thermo Aquatuner*.

[image: Before Heating]

As expected the coolant got cooled by exactly **-14.0 ℃** down to **-49.1 ℃**.

[image: After Heating]

### Calculations and Expected Result

[Insulated Tiles](https://oxygennotincluded.fandom.com/wiki/Insulated_Tile) of the box are made of [Insulation](https://oxygennotincluded.fandom.com/wiki/Insulation) which has *Thermal Conductivity* of **0.0**. This means the box itself cannot heat up or cool down, it also perfectly insulates its contents preventing any heat exchange between the insides and the outsides.

As an extra measure to prevent unwanted heat exchange, the area outside of the box is vacuumed.

So, since neither the box itself nor the vacuum outside of it could exchange heat I assumed that all the heat "extracted" from the coolant should go to the insides of the box.

Here's the inventory of the box contents:

- 1 [Thermo Aquatuner](https://oxygennotincluded.fandom.com/wiki/Thermo_Aquatuner) made of *Thermium* with a mass of **1200 kg**
- 1 piece of [Conductive Wire](https://oxygennotincluded.fandom.com/wiki/Conductive_Wire) made of *Thermium* with a mass of **25 kg**
- 2 pieces of [Insulated Liquid Pipe](https://oxygennotincluded.fandom.com/wiki/Insulated_Liquid_Pipe) made of *Insulation* with a mass of **400 kg** each
- 2 cells of [Polluted Water](https://oxygennotincluded.fandom.com/wiki/Polluted_Water) with a mass of **1 kg** each
- 2 cells of [Water](https://oxygennotincluded.fandom.com/wiki/Water) with a mass of **1 kg** each

[Insulated Liquid Pipes](https://oxygennotincluded.fandom.com/wiki/Insulated_Liquid_Pipe) are made of [Insulation](https://oxygennotincluded.fandom.com/wiki/Insulation), so they don't participate in the heat exchange.

For the reference, here are the properties of the materials exchanging heat:

| Material | Specific Heat Capacity, DTU/g/℃ | Mass, kg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [Water](https://oxygennotincluded.fandom.com/wiki/Water) | 4.179 | 2 |
| [Polluted Water](https://oxygennotincluded.fandom.com/wiki/Polluted_Water) | 4.179 | 2 |
| [Thermium](https://oxygennotincluded.fandom.com/wiki/Thermium) | 0.622 | 1225 |
| [Super Coolant](https://oxygennotincluded.fandom.com/wiki/Super_Coolant) | 8.440 | 4 |

1. *Heat* required to heat up an object is the product of material's *heat capacity* and *temperature change*:

   ΔQ = C × ΔT
2. *Heat capacity* is the product of *specific heat capacity* and *mass* of the material:

   C = c × m
3. *Temperature change* is the product of *specific heat capacity* and *mass* of the material:

   ΔT = T<sub>final</sub> − T<sub>initial</sub>
4. Given the formulae above the amount of heat given by the coolant is this:

   ΔQ<sub>super coolant</sub> = c × m × (T<sub>final</sub> − T<sub>initial</sub>)

   ΔQ<sub>super coolant</sub> = 8.440 × 4 × (−49.1 − (−35.1))

   ΔQ<sub>super coolant</sub> = 8.440 × 4 × (−14)

   ΔQ<sub>super coolant</sub> = −472.64 kDTU

   Note, the result is negative because the coolant is cooled instead of heated.

   Also note, it's **kDTU** not **DTU** since mass is in **kg** not in **g**.
5. Since the system is closed (no heat is received from the outside, none is dissipated either), the *heat* amount stays the same, in other words the heat change is zero:

   ΔQ<sub>super coolant</sub> + ΔQ<sub>box contents</sub> = 0

   ΔQ<sub>box contents</sub> = −ΔQ<sub>super coolant</sub>
6. Assuming we give the system enough time to stabilize, the initial temperature of the box contents is going to be the same for all its parts such as pipes, wires, liquids, devices, etc. The same applies to the final temperature.

   Therefore we can treat the box contents as a single pseudo-object that has some *heat capacity*, so having formula `(1)` in mind we get the following:

   ΔQ<sub>box contents</sub> = C<sub>box contents</sub> × ΔT<sub>box contents</sub>
7. *Heat capacity* of the box contents is the sum of heat capacities of its parts:

   C<sub>box contents</sub> = C<sub>thermo aquatuner</sub> + C<sub>conductive wire</sub> + C<sub>water</sub> + C<sub>polluted water</sub>

   C<sub>box contents</sub> = m<sub>thermo aquatuner</sub> × c<sub>thermium</sub> + m<sub>conductive wire</sub> × c<sub>thermium</sub> + m<sub>water</sub> × c<sub>water</sub> + m<sub>polluted water</sub> × c<sub>polluted water</sub>

   C<sub>box contents</sub> = (m<sub>thermo aquatuner</sub> + m<sub>conductive wire</sub>) × c<sub>thermium</sub> + m<sub>water</sub> × c<sub>water</sub> + m<sub>polluted water</sub> × c<sub>polluted water</sub>

   C<sub>box contents</sub> = (1200 + 25) × 0.622 + 2 × 4.179 + 2 × 4.179

   C<sub>box contents</sub> = 1225 × 0.622 + 2 × 4.179 + 2 × 4.179

   C<sub>box contents</sub> = 761.95 + 8.358 + 8.358

   C<sub>box contents</sub> = 778.666 kDTU/℃
8. Now starting from the formula `(6)` and substituting formulae `(3)`, `(5)`, `(4)` and `(7)` we can derive the final temperature of the box contents:

   ΔQ<sub>box contents</sub> = C<sub>box contents</sub> × ΔT<sub>box contents</sub>

   ΔT<sub>box contents</sub> = ΔQ<sub>box contents</sub> ÷ C<sub>box contents</sub>

   T<sub>box contents final</sub> − T<sub>box contents initial</sub> = ΔQ<sub>box contents</sub> ÷ C<sub>box contents</sub>

   T<sub>box contents final</sub> = ΔQ<sub>box contents</sub> ÷ C<sub>box contents</sub> + T<sub>box contents initial</sub>

   T<sub>box contents final</sub> = −ΔQ<sub>super coolant</sub> ÷ C<sub>box contents</sub> + T<sub>box contents initial</sub>

   T<sub>box contents final</sub> = −ΔQ<sub>super coolant</sub> ÷ C<sub>box contents</sub> + T<sub>box contents initial</sub>

   T<sub>box contents final</sub> = −(−472.64) ÷ 778.666 + 10.0

   T<sub>box contents final</sub> = 472.64 ÷ 778.666 + 10.0

   T<sub>box contents final</sub> ≈ 10.6℃

So the conclusion is that after the box contents get heated and all its contents parts take their time to balance the temperature the final temperature of the box contents would be 10.6℃.

### Actual Result

And here's the actual results that I got in the game:

[image: Final State]

The actual temperature is 12.8℃ instead of 10.6℃ calculated above.

I would appreciate any clues as to where I made a mistake in my calculations.

Comment: Hi Ihor, great first question! Welcome to Arqade!

Comment: Out of curiosity, are the results the same if you send in a single 4 kg packet of Super Coolant, or 2*2kg packets? Just trying to find ways to find what the variable might be.

Comment: @SimonForsberg, just tried packets of different sizes: starting from 10 kg and down to 100g each. Turns out, the size of the "pieces" doesn't matter as long as the "whole" stays the same. At least that makes sense to me.